# Read a variable length integer from the supplied InputStream

Tags: java, utf-8, stream, bit-manipulation, inputstream

I was looking a bit above the Netflix Hollow library code (https://github.com/Netflix/hollow) and I found this function to which I can't find any sense (Warning: I don't know much about Java ).
Theoretically, the function returns a variable-length integer from the InputStream.

```
/**
 * Read a variable length integer from the supplied InputStream
 */
public static int readVInt(InputStream in) throws IOException {
    byte b = (byte)in.read();

    if(b == (byte) 0x80)
        throw new RuntimeException("Attempting to read null value as int");

    int value = b & 0x7F;
    while ((b & 0x80) != 0) {
      b = (byte)in.read();
      value <<= 7;
      value |= (b & 0x7F);
    }

    return value;
}
```

I comment my doubts:

1) **Int value = b & 0x7F** : The result of this is always b, right? What's the point?

2) **while ((b & 0x80) != 0)** : The result of **b & 0x80** (If b is an integer digit, that is, coded in decimal from 0 to 9, would be 48-57 in decimal) is always 0. Therefore, will never enter the loop...

Comment: Hola Toni! The key point is here: `if b is an integer digit, coded in decimal...` -- it is not. `b` here is used as a pure `byte`, to store the bits received. Check my answer for a more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, it's kind of weird (IMHO) to find such low level implementations in Java; this kind of logic is more usual in C programs and other "close to the metal" languages. But I guess efficient streaming to millions of users doesn't come for free :)

`b` is a `byte`, not an integer. It's interpreted as 8 bits.
`0x80` is `10000000`, a mask with all bits set to zero except the higher-order ("first") one.
`0x7F` is `01111111`, a mask with all bits set to one except the first one. The inverse of `0x80`.
`value` is the integer value we want to read. This is an `int` which is 4 bytes in Java. So `00000000000000000000000000000000` initially.

The code reads a sequence of bytes, one by one. It uses the first bit as a mark for termination (0 means "last byte"), and concatenates the other 7 bits to `value`. The masks are applied to evaluate just those bits. So `b & 0x80` is used to check if the first bit is set, while `b & 0x7F` is used to set the first bit to zero and keep the value of all the other bits.

Example:

- We want to transmit the number 24612135 byte per byte. This is `1011101111000110100100111` in binary.
- We split it in groups of 7 bits: `0001011 1011110 0011010 0100111` and make every group a 1-leading 8-bit byte, save for the last one which will be marked as 0-leading: `10001011 11011110 10011010 00100111`
- First byte gets read. So `b = 10001011`. Since this is not `0x80` (`10000000`), we know this is going to be a valid, non-null integer.
- We discard the first bit (`b & 0x7f` is `00001011`) and set `value` to that. Now `value` is `00000000000000000000000000001011`
- Now this could be a one-byte number, so we have to check for the first bit to know if we should continue reading. `b & 0x80` is not 0, so we enter the loop to read more bytes.
- Read the second byte. Now `b = 11011110`. Discard first bit (`b & 0x7f`) and put the other 7 bits inside `value`. But `value` already has some bits set, so we have to shift them to make room for 7 more bits: `value <<= 7`. Now `value` is `00000000000000000000010110000000`. By using the bitwise OR operator `value |= (b & 0x7F)` we set the lowest 7 bits to the right value. Now `value` is `00000000000000000000010111011110`.
- The second byte didn't have the first bit set to 0 either, so we loop again for the third byte. Same logic; now `value` is `00000000000000101110111100011010`.
- The third byte also didn't have the first bit set to 0; loop again for the fourth byte, `00100111`. Now `value` is `00000001011101111000110100100111`. This is the correct value that we intended to send.
- Because the fourth byte did have the first bit set to zero, the loop's break condition now evaluates to true, so we stop reading bytes.

Anyways, I hope this helped you.

Comment: I was kinda too lazy to write down all the bit stuff - glad that somebody came by and added that level of detail!

Comment: Thanks. This is one of those things that takes barely 5 minutes to explain with a pen on a napkin, but... it's a pain to translate to an answer with markup etc. :/

Comment: Not that weird right? Netflix api here is reading binary snapshots, and everything is optimized in heap memory. Cool stuff

Answer (score 0):

The point is: probably they are using their "own" protocol that determines how to write **and** read values using streams.

And in that protocol, the value 0x80 has the special meaning: "end of value".

Meaning: the "writer" parts writes a sequence of bytes, and then put a 0x80 to signal that no more bytes will be following. And then:

```
while ((b & 0x80) != 0) {
```

evaluates to **false** when 0x8? is read. Meaning: if that first bit is set, then "end of message".

In other words: when you want to read an int from that stream; and the first byte you get is 0x80 - then: "no value for your"; thus the exception.

Then you just reading byte by byte; and you shift those bytes into the result int value - until that 0x80 "end of value" marker byte comes in.

Comment: But for this to work that way, they must code the digits 0 through 9 with values greater than 0x80, otherwise the "AND logic" will always be evaluated as 0 and will never enter the loop... is this what you mean?

Comment: I updated my answer: the point is: an initial 0x80 ... no number. And any other bit later on that has that first bit set ... indicates end of value.